# Facebook api on windows without keyboard? Virtual Keyboard

Tags: jquery, windows, facebook, google-chrome

I am building a web application that will be loaded into a chrome browser on a system with a touch screen.  The kiosk will be using the Facebook api to allow members to login, but how do I get The Facebook to require a virtual keyboard... how to I get this to work on form fields I don't control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with vanilla JavaScript. Instead, install or create a virtual keyboard plugin for Chrome.

For example:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mpphfcjpaldmedbbomcdhgonmhjngfig